# Styling search results WordPress

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress

**Edit: Please could you tell me why my post doesn't provide enough information or if I am not following any rules rather than just down voting my question.**

I would like to edit the css for this page http://jacobstone.co.uk/leggera2/?s=the which displays search results.

I only need to add some padding so that the results aren't all clumped together.
I've been stuck on this one for a while now so I thought I'd ask you guys. 
I tried wrapping the php loop (in functions) that calls the search results in a div class but this didn't work.

Do I need to create a new php page for these results or can I add a bit of html to somewhere (eg. functions php) that will allow me to add classes / ids to elements?

functions.php: (the function SearchFilter bit is what calls the results)
is it possible to add classes to the search results?

```
<?php 

function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}

function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );


if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

add_filter( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', 'my_widget_tag_cloud_args' );
function my_widget_tag_cloud_args( $args ) {
    $args['number'] = 20;
    $args['largest'] = 18;
    $args['smallest'] = 10;
    $args['unit'] = 'px';
    return $args;
}

?>
```

**I want to add classes to my search results, in the same way as I added classes to elements in page.php:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span8" id="page">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, this page does not exist.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

 </div>
  <div class="span4" id="page">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
  </div>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: Sorry, what code would you like to see? CSS and functions?

Comment: The most relevant one for your problem...

Comment: Use a browser like google chrome, and right click and select "Inspect Element" if my memory serves me right. You will get a list of relevent styles relevent to what you inspect

Comment: Not sure what you've changed in the theme, but on the demo of the actual theme here = http://320press.com/wpbs/?s=test it adds the page name to the body class, so you could do `.search .post {}` If you look on the demo site the body tag is `<body class="search search-results" data-twttr-rendered="true">`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Sorry I should have clarified, I know how to style the elements but, with it being WordPress, I don't have editable HTML and as far as I understand all html elements are called by PHP. @ Nick the theme is only very loosely based on WPBS and I have coded almost everything from scratch.

Comment: If you want to add classes to search results, you could do it in the functions that print the title and the content, adding there the needed HTML.

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan thanks for your reply, this sounds like what I want to do. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: I believe that this is the code that prints the title and content: `function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');`

Comment: I think what I need to see is what goes inside the functions the_title() and the_content().

Comment: I think you can see that in the page.php code I included in my original post

Comment: No, Jacob, in your posted code there are only the calls to the functions. I want to see what is inside the functions.

Comment: Sorry, where might I find what's inside?

Comment: In the source code of your website. If you can't find it, who can?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for, you're not being very specific... PHP code? The title and content parentheses are empty as you can see. You can view my source code just as easily as I can using web inspector.

Comment: How can I see PHP code in a client browser? I just can't. If you want to add classes to the elements that compose the snippets (a title and a paragraph) you have to access the functions that display them and modify the sentences that print the HTML code. I suppose that the_title() and the_content() are those functions. But their inner code is not shown here.

Comment: Okay I understand now. The PHP files that I have not already disclosed are footer.php, front-page.php, header.php, home.php, index.php, page.php, searchpage.php and sidebar.php. Any idea in which I might find the relevant code? Thanks

Comment: Index.php:   `<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span8" id="page">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
    <?php the_content(); ?> 

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <h1>Search Results</h1>
 <p class="noresults"><?php _e('Sorry, this page doesn&#8217;t exist.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

 </div>
  <div class="span4" id="page">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
  </div>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: Just the file where those functions are. Open the PHP files in a text editor and search for the functions called the_title and the_content... Because those files have too generic names and I have no idea... or you may send your PHP files to zahra_okume@hotmail.com and I will peer them.

Answer (score 0):

the first block of code that you have in your question is this the same page that the results are returned to or do you display these on a separate page, at the moment i am working on a project doing similar things the way i have done it is:

`<function page>`

this is where all of your function are run and then returned the values correctly this tends to be the largest page

`<end of function page>`

`<content pages >`

these are all the pages that the values get returned to its save all the functions on the page and then you can style them how you want using css and html tags either by outputting them to the screen using php or simple html.

`</end of content page>`

Comment: I think that the results are simply returned to page.php, I have added this code to my original post if that's any help. So I can have the actual loop in functions and then 'print' this in my page.php, adding a class to the loop? Sorry I'm a little confused still!